# Phonegap change button value onclick

Tags: javascript, android, button, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working with phonegap and have some buttons like this:

```
<input id="my_button" type="button" onclick="my_function();"/>
```

I want to capture the click event to change the button's value,

```
my_function () {
    alert('42');
    document.getElementById('my_button').value = 'foo bar baz';
}
```

When I test that code in my phone the alert is displayed, but the buttons value stays the same...

PD: I'm also using jquery mobile, don't know if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try setting `document.getElementById('my_button').text`

Answer (score 0):

To update the text of a jQuery Mobile button widget you can use the `.button()` method that jQuery Mobile exposes. This is helpful because different types of buttons (`<a/ >`/`<input />`/`<button />`) need to be updated differently.

Here's an example:

```
my_function () {
    $("#my_button").val("foo bar baz").button("refresh");
}
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4YPHe/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method of **jquery**.
For eg:  `$("#my_button").attr('value','you_can_change_your_value_here');`
Happy Coding !!